# Custom messages for unit tests in MSTest

Tags: visual-studio-2012, customization, mstest

Is there a way that I can customize or otherwise add custom content to the output window?  For example, if I have a test case that compares two text files and they don't match, can I somehow place a button in the output window (where the error messages normally appear) that would open the contents of the files in a diff tool?

It seems to me that there should be a way to make this happen, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: The only possible way I can think is to create a plugin for visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt mechanism to allow you to do this. Like Schaliasos mentions a custom plugin would be the route to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("My Message");` and `Console.WriteLine("My Message");` worked well for me. You can then view the output from the test Explorer results window if you need to.

This is the solution presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589944/254215